# What does my code finding biconnected components of a graph not operate well?

Tags: c++, graph-algorithm

I would like to determine the biconnected components of a graph. In my code I need to use the vector of edges laying on a given node (myEdges). Could you help me why I get edges with biCompID = -1 after the decomposition? My code is the following:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "edge.h"
#include "node.h"

node::node(int nb)
   : nb(nb), biLow(-1), biDisc(-1), biParent(NULL)
   {}

edge::edge(int nb, node* firstNode, node* secondNode)
         : nb(nb), firstNode(firstNode), secondNode(secondNode), biCompID(-1)
      {}
node* edge::getOtherNode(node* nd)
{
   if(firstNode == nd)
   {
      return secondNode;
   }
   else
   {
      return firstNode;
   }
}

void BCCD(vector<node*> nodes, vector<edge*> edges);

int main()
{
   vector<edge*> edges;
   vector<node*> nodes;
   vector<pair<int,int>> list;

   ifstream data;
   data.open("bicon.txt",ios::in);   
//
// Construct the graph from the input
//
   int a, b;
   while(!data.eof())
   {
      data >> a >> b;
      list.push_back(make_pair(a,b));
   }
   int nNodes = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < (int)list.size(); i++)
   {
       if (nNodes < list[i].first) nNodes = list[i].first;
       if (nNodes < list[i].second) nNodes = list[i].second;
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < nNodes; i++) nodes.push_back(new node(i));
   for (int i = 0; i < (int)list.size(); i++) 
       edges.push_back(new edge(i, nodes[list[i].first - 1], nodes[list[i].second - 1]));
//
// Save the edges of each node 
//
   edge* actEdge;
   for (int i = 0; i < (int)edges.size(); i++)
   {
      actEdge = edges[i];
      actEdge->firstNode->myEdges.push_back(actEdge);
      if(actEdge->firstNode != actEdge->secondNode) 
               actEdge->secondNode->myEdges.push_back(actEdge);
   }
//
// Decompose the graph into biconnected components
//
   BCCD(nodes, edges);
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
void biDFS(node* actNode, vector<edge*> &stackEdges, vector<edge*> &resultEdges, int &biCompID)
{
   static int count = 0;
   actNode->biDisc = actNode->biLow = ++count;
   int nChildren = 0;
   node* otherNode;
   edge *neighborEdge, *stackEdge, *resultEdge;
   bool cond1, cond2, cond3, cond4;
   for (int i = 0; i < (int)actNode->myEdges.size(); i++)
   {
      neighborEdge = actNode->myEdges[i];
      otherNode = neighborEdge->getOtherNode(actNode);
      if (otherNode->biDisc == -1)
      {
         nChildren++;
         otherNode->biParent = actNode;
         stackEdges.push_back(neighborEdge);
         biDFS(otherNode, stackEdges, resultEdges, biCompID);
         actNode->biLow = min(actNode->biLow, otherNode->biLow);
         if (actNode->biParent == NULL && nChildren > 1 || actNode->biParent != NULL && otherNode->biLow >= actNode->biDisc)
         {
            biCompID++;
            for(;;)
            {
               stackEdge = stackEdges.back();
               stackEdge->biCompID = biCompID;
               stackEdges.pop_back();
               if (stackEdge == neighborEdge) break;
               resultEdges.push_back(stackEdge);
            }
         }
      }
      else if (otherNode != actNode->biParent)
      {
         actNode->biLow = min(actNode->biLow, otherNode->biDisc);
         cond1 = cond2 = cond3 = cond4 = false;
         for (int j = 0; j < (int)stackEdges.size() && !cond1 && !cond2; j++)
         {
             stackEdge = stackEdges[j];
             if (stackEdge == neighborEdge) cond1 = true;
             if (stackEdge->firstNode == otherNode && stackEdge->secondNode == actNode) cond2 = true;
         }
         for (int j = 0; j < (int)resultEdges.size() && !cond3 && !cond4; j++)
         {
             resultEdge = resultEdges[j];
             if (resultEdge == neighborEdge) cond3 = true;
             if (resultEdge->firstNode == otherNode && resultEdge->secondNode == actNode) cond4 = true;
         }
         if (!cond1 && !cond2 && !cond3 && !cond4) 
         {
             stackEdges.push_back(neighborEdge);
         }
      }
   }
}
void BCCD(vector<node*> nodes, vector<edge*> edges)
{
   int biCompID = -1;
   vector<edge*> stackEdges;
   vector<edge*> resultEdges;
   node* actNode;
   edge* stackEdge;
   unsigned stackSize;
   for (int i = 0; i < (int)nodes.size(); i++)
   {
      actNode = nodes[i];
      if (actNode->biDisc  == -1) biDFS(actNode, stackEdges, resultEdges, biCompID);
      stackSize = stackEdges.size();
      if (stackSize != 0)
      {
         biCompID++;
         while (stackSize > 0)
         {
            stackEdge = stackEdges.back();
            stackEdge->biCompID = biCompID;
            stackEdges.pop_back();
            resultEdges.push_back(stackEdge);
            stackSize--;
         }
      }
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < (int)edges.size(); i++) cout << edges[i]->biCompID << endl;
}
```

The header files are:

**stdafx.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
```

**node.h**

```
class edge;

class node
{
public:
      node(int nb);
      int nb;
      vector<edge*> myEdges;
      int biLow, biDisc;
      node* biParent;
};
```

**edge.h**

class node;

```
class edge
{
public:
      edge(int nb, node* firstNode, node* secondNode);
      int nb;
      node *firstNode, *secondNode;
      int biCompID;
      node* getOtherNode(node* nd);
};
```

A "good" input (`bicon.txt`) is:

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
2 4
3 5
2 6
6 7
1 7
6 8
6 9
8 9
9 10
11 12
```

My wrong input can be found on https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BywmWaXkwDsNbHltVGd3TFBtNWM/view?usp=sharing.

Comment: Which is easier: you find a way to post the failure case, or we *guess* the failure case?

Comment: Could you please help me how to attach it?

Comment: How big is the *minimal* failure case?

Comment: I have attached the "wrong" input as google link (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BywmWaXkwDsNbHltVGd3TFBtNWM/view?usp=sharing.). This is the only case which showed edges with biCompID=-1. I have tested my code for several small graphs, but I could not find small failure case. :(

Comment: So if you remove any edge from that failure case, the failure disappears?

Comment: Do you see any mistake in my code? :(